# Customizing entity generation from datasource in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, intellij-idea

I want to generate my JPA-Entities from the database schema of an SQL Server 2012 using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.2.

I created a new data source and connected via JDBC to the server. Everything including the generation of the entities from database schema works.

The problem is, that the ID fields in my database are NUMERIC(15), but IntelliJ generates Integers. Because of Integer beeing too small for my IDs, I run into errors.

Do I have a chance of IntelliJ generating Long instead of Integer? I can't find any settings in the IDE regarding the code generation.

I know, that I can change the datatype of every field in the generation dialog, but that's not a real option regarding 100 tables with primary and foreign keys, that need to be changed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe this article will be helpful for you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/mapping-by-database-schema.html